# woocommerce - paypal error if the checkout price goes more than 1000 euros

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

In my wordpress app created the store with payment(paypal express) option using woocommerce plugin, checkout works fine if the price is less than 1000 euros but when the price goes beyond 1000 euros getting the below error.

> The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
>   (10413)

Comment: That question issue is not about programming, so you should ask respective support pages for woocommerce or/and Paypal…

Comment: Can you include the request log to PayPal in your question?